# How to use Gmail API for sending email in android development

Tags: android, email

I need to send email in android. Initially I used android intent for sending email. But every time it is asking me to select the email client. So I moved to the JavaMail API concept. But this API asking username and password in code itself. So my friend suggest me to use Gmail API instead of JavaMail API. if anyone knows the idea or having any link about Gmail API, pls share it with me.

Comment: I posted this a little while ago, does this help? [sending email with gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424719/send-email-without-password/30157213#30157213)

Comment: were you able to send email using gmail api ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Gmail Rest Api for sending the email. You can refer this link

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: yeah i have reviewed this link... really am unable to understand it..little bit confusing.

Comment: I haven't tried this before. just for your sake i was checking it. Here is the example for it https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/sendEmail.java

Comment: I have tried this code..But getting error in "Gmail service". I imported all the packages in dependencies file. still couldnt resolve this error